# Seeking testnet and wallet for students to learn how to use ethereum?

Tags: wallets, testnets, simulation

I have a class on finance and have been trying to make it relatively painless for students to learn about getting a wallet, Ethereum address, learn about transaction hash and block, etc. Unfortunately I see that testnets have been deprecated and I'm looking for a way to accomplish this. It can be something as simple as using a wallet like metamask to generate addresses and perform a few transactions that can be looked up online at etherscan. Can anyone provide some advice on what wallet and testnet environment would be useful for this? This could include a simulation that students could use (or a PC running an app that simulated the environment) that might provide the same type of experience.

Answer (score 2):

Every MetaMask instance comes with a default node to a few testnets, so all you need to do is install MetaMask and switch in there to a testnet (eg Ethereum Sepolia or Ethereum Holesky that's launching Sept 28) and just go from there.

You can fund the accounts with testnet ETH eg at https://faucet.chainstack.com/

If you want to do more advanced developer stuff, you can also get free nodes (RPC endpoints) on the free tier from any provider that's out there. Chainstack for example provides 3M calls for free on the free Developer plan — more than enough for a bunch of tutorials. Any node provider will work.

Comment: Thank you. I will check this out tomorrow (quite timely news!) as one of the main problems has been funding testnet accounts.

Comment: Unfortunately Chainstack requires you to enter credit card information. The video and process has a whiff of dishonesty in baiting. The video informs you that you can get .5 Sepolia ETH every 24 hours and that you can sign up. But then quickly skips past the signup process saying 'but if you already have a chainstack account'. Right. They specifically don't show you that you need to confirm your email and then find out the surprise that you can't go past the credit card entry screen. No details, no link to info, nada. Just a paywall. Not comfortable here & certainly not for students.

Comment: Eh, I wouldn't call it dishonesty since it's specifically a Chainstack faucet and there needs to be some form of protection from draining it + having to register with the platform distributing the funds is a fair deal (it's free).

That said, hit me up and I can get you some SepoliaETH no problem. Although then you'd have to manage the distribution to your students yourself.

Comment: Thanks Ake - very much appreciated and kind of you. Appreciate what you're saying and I do appreciate the need for quid pro quo. Coming from a strong tech background from way back in the day, this kind of data collection marketing tactic just disappointed me as they didn't need to do it that way.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience the easiest ecosystem to get started and test a few transactions like you mention would be Polygon Mumbai testnet.

You have to manually add it to Metamask, but getting a few testnet eth is fairly easy on their official faucet.

https://faucet.polygon.technology/

Also, paradigm has a multitestnet and multiasset faucet.I think you need to sign in woth Twitter but they will aridrop you different ERC20 and ERC721 tokens to your wallet, which should be more than enough to show around and make some transactions.

https://faucet.paradigm.xyz/

Answer (score 0):

my favorite solution for learning to use blockchains, run:

`anvil --fork-url https://rpc.ankr.com/eth`

then point your wallet (metamask, rabby, whatever) to this chain.

also https://impersonator.xyz/ is pretty useful

Answer (score 0):

I thank some of you above but the methods are not for blockchain beginner students. Too complicated for them in all respects. I didn't want to use a system that requires a credit card. Instead, I received some funds for Sepolia from Chainlink and also from Quicknode. You can tweet for some SepoliaETH although it requires a metamask account to already be funded with ETH, which I had. No floor amount required. I'm going to see if I can get more from a Sepolia faucet or source but hopefully it will be enough to send and receive between students. Any other suggestions to receive small amounts like this for educational purposes (sending, receiving, analyzing block explorers, etc.)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).